# keyof typeof cannot find name

Tags: javascript, typescript, keyof

I attempted to provide a type definition that defines an object as `any`, because as of now it's fairly open-ended as to what it could be.  As well, it has a key for a property within this object.

```
type Props = {
    obj: any;
    objKey: keyof typeof obj;
};
```

The result is an error on the line for `objKey` stating:
`Cannot find name 'obj'`

If I use this inline with the function arguments, it works without issue as seen below.

```
({ obj, objKey }: { obj: any; objKey: keyof typeof obj })
```

Why would this error/warning by produced in the lone type definition, and not the inline argument typing?

Comment: You ca use `objKey: keyof Props['obj']` but since `obj` is `any` that will be equivalent to `PropertyKey` anyway. If you are trying to create objects that have this rule checked, you will need to use a function to do the checking

Comment: It doesn't error in the second example because you have destructured `obj` (which is defining something named `obj`).

Comment: This feels like an XY problem; the answer to your q is "it doesn't work in the first case because there's no value named `obj`, but in the second case you are creating such a value via destructuring". But the approach itself isn't useful; you might as well just write `{obj: any, objKey: string | number | symbol}`, which is the same thing and unlikely to be what you're looking for.  What should we do with this question?  Answer it as-is even though it's not going to help you achieve a goal?  Or refactor to be where you ask about your goal directly and not about why your attempt failed?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a generic type parameter:

```
type Props<P> = {
    obj: P;
    objKey: keyof P;
}
```